# The Expression "Drop it." Stop talking about it

Tags: grammar, phrasal-verbs

There are some phrasal verbs with drop, such as:

- Drop in
- Drop by
- Drop off
- Drop out
- etc...

I saw the expression "Just drop it" used in a movie to express 'stop talking about it'.

I'm just curious if "drop it" is a phrasal verb as well, because I haven't found anything about it on Google, or is it just a simple verb + pronoun.

Comment: ***Phrasal verb:***
a phrase that consists of a ​verb with a ​preposition or ​adverb or both, the ​meaning of which is different from the ​meaning of ​its ​separate ​parts:
*"Pay for", "​work out", and "make up for" are all ​phrasal ​verbs.* http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/phrasal-verb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There needs to be a phrase for there to be a phrasal verb.  The prepositions "in," "by," "off," and "out" when added to "drop" make phrases.  In "Just drop it," the verb is only the single word "drop."  This is simply an idiomatic use of "drop" meaning to abandon a topic of conversation.

Comment: Very good point. In fact, if you look up the many definitions of 'drop' you can find this:-  2a :  give up 2, abandon <drop an idea> <drop the charges>  --- http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drop